# How to extract values from a text file and rearrange them using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a rather large text file containing a very long list of values. Out of this file I am required to  extract the values of magnitude, surface area and volume, which are then to be rearranged into columns titled accorgingly.

The data currently has the format:

{columns of unneeded data}

```
magnitude         :             38.662 +-    0.0556 N        
surface area      :             31.882 +-    0.0584 m^2
volume            :             545.56 +-    0.6562 m^3
```

{columns of unneeded data}

```
magnitude         :             38.682 +-    0.0606 N        
surface area      :             31.832 +-    0.0587 m^2
volume            :             545.78 +-    0.6362 m^3
```

Required output:

```
magnitude         surface area          volume
38.662+-0.0556 N  31.882+-0.0584 m^2    545.56+-0.6562 m^3
38.682+-0.0606 N  31.832+-0.0587 m^2    545.78+-0.6362 m^3
```

I am using bash and have tried:

```
grep -e 'magnitude|surface area|volume' '{print}' original_file.txt > new_file.txt
```

N.B. I am not an expert in Bash scripting.

Comment: These are rows of data IMHO. If always 3 rows are to be captured, iterate over the file by increment of 3 lines, split at  separator `:`, with `awk` or `cut`. Then print as columns.

Comment: Yes. I am working on a text file containing several rows of data, which I am to manipulate. I do not know which lines the values of magnitude etc. are in. The required values are also separated by other unneeded values. I was thinking about using grep to find lines which contain 'magnitude' etc and then print those.

Comment: Okay @dan. Please can you provide a more detailed excerpt of the text file?

Comment: Searching for those keywords in "very line columns" (as you posted elsewhere) is expensive. As an efficient first step, either by itself or as the first line of any awk, immediately discard any lines too long to be the ones you are searching for, e.g. : `length > 100 { next; }`. Also, when searching for the keywords, anchor the search to start of line using an initial "^".

Answer (score 0):

Well, most likely not the most elegant solution, but it should work:

```
awk -F':' 'BEGIN { print "magnitude\tsurface area\tvolume" } /magnitude/,/volume/{gsub(/[ \t]+/, "", $2); printf $(2); printf " "; if (/volume/){printf "\n"}}' YOUR_FILE.txt
```

This produces:

```
magnitude   surface area    volume
38.662+-0.0556N 31.882+-0.0584m^2 545.56+-0.6562m^3 
38.662+-0.0556N 31.882+-0.0584m^2 545.56+-0.6562m^3
```

Input:

```
junk
junk
junk
magnitude         :             38.662 +-    0.0556 N        
surface area      :             31.882 +-    0.0584 m^2
volume            :             545.56 +-    0.6562 m^3  
junk
junk
magnitude         :             38.662 +-    0.0556 N        
surface area      :             31.882 +-    0.0584 m^2
volume            :             545.56 +-    0.6562 m^3  
junk
```

Using `gawk`:

```
gawk -F':' 'BEGIN { print "magnitude\tsurface area\tvolume" } /magnitude/,/volume/{gsub(/[ \t]+/, "", $2); $2=gensub(/([Nm]+[23^]*)/, " \\1", "g", $(2)); printf $(2); printf "   "; if (/volume/){printf "\n"}}' YOUR_FILE.txt
```

Result:

```
magnitude   surface area    volume
38.662+-0.0556 N   31.882+-0.0584 m^2   545.56+-0.6562 m^3 
38.662+-0.0556 N   31.882+-0.0584 m^2   545.56+-0.6562 m^3
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Grep interested lines.
2. Used `sed` to read 3 consecutive lines and to insert column separators into the input and merge the 3 lines.
3. Used `column` to output.

```
grep 'magnitude\|surface area\|volume' original_file.txt |
sed '
s/^magnitude *: *\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) *\([^ ]* [^ ]*\) */\1\2\3/
N
s/\nsurface area *: *\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) *\([^ ]* [^ ]*\) */|\1\2\3/
N
s/\nvolume *: *\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) *\([^ ]* [^ ]*\) */|\1\2\3/
' |
column -t -s '|' -N 'magnitude,surface area,volume' -o '  '
```

For such contents of `original_file.txt`:

```
dfasfdasfa
magnitude         :             38.662 +-    0.0556 N
surface area      :             31.882 +-    0.0584 m^2
volume            :             545.56 +-    0.6562 m^3
fasdfdasfafa
magnitude         :             38.682 +-    0.0606 N
surface area      :             31.832 +-    0.0587 m^2
volume            :             545.78 +-    0.6362 m^3
fdasfdasfa
```

The script would output:

```
magnitude         surface area        volume
38.662+-0.0556 N  31.882+-0.0584 m^2  545.56+-0.6562 m^3
38.662+-0.0556 N  31.882+-0.0584 m^2  545.56+-0.6562 m^3
```

Comment: Is there something like the CTAN `blindtext` package for Bash?

Comment: `CTAN blindtext package` - what is that? [this](https://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext)? Erm.. Is your comment intended for this post?

Comment: Generates some blindtext. As the OP did not provide full sample I'd wondered how to create some text instead of `fdasfdasfa` as you did.

Comment: I can only think of `cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd '[:print:]'` or like `cat /usr/share/dict/* | shuf | fmt | head -n5`.